# Oracle 11g Express Edition for Windows 64bit?

Tags: windows, oracle, 64-bit, oracle-xe

I registered on http://Oracle.com in order to download 11g R2 Express edition database. But http://Oracle.com offered me download links only for Windows 32bit and for Linux 64bit.

Is there somewhere 64bit Windows version of Oracle 11g XE database?  Are 64bit versions available only for paid Oracle db?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no Windows 64-bit version of Oracle Express Edition. You'll have to go for Standard/Enterprise editions.

Comment: is there any performance loss when i will use 32bit version on 64bit win? Or it is better to use 10g? thx

Comment: I don't know, that depends on your usage. Mixmatching architectures is not a good idea. @sanjuro

Comment: ok thank you very much, i will try 11g 32bit and i will see how it will performs on 64bit system, if there will be problems i'll switch to 10g

Comment: @sanjuro the website warns "Does not work on Windows x64"… does it?

Comment: @fudo it actually works, just doesn't installs cleanly: http://luminite.org/2012/09/06/installing-oracle-database-xe-11g-on-windows-7-64-bit-machine/

Answer (score 35):

## There is

I used this blog post to install it in my machine: http://luminite.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/installing-oracle-database-xe-11g-on-windows-7-64-bit-machine/

The only thing you have to do is replace a registry value during the installation, I've done it about three times already, and every time found a different reference on-line, none here on stackoverflow.

EDIT: as @kc2001 noted, regedit must be run as Administrator, and added this tutorial: (a bit more colorful): http://www.hanmiaojuan.com/2013/03/install-oracle-xe-11g-for-windows7-64bits.html

Comment: I just did this and it worked perfectly for me. This answer should be voted up more because it's the only one that actually worked.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The blog does provide a workaround, which is basically this - A file, "Key_XE.reg", referenced by the installer can't be found, so you need to provide the correct path.  In regedit, set  key"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\266B7A503A089BE4EAD1986A429434C1\SourceList\Media\1" = "C:\Users\[YOUR USER ID]\AppData\Local\Temp\{GUID}".  You'll need to replace [YOUR USER ID] with your windows user name, and {GUID} is the GUID shown in the installer error message.

Comment: Some additional info - for me, the Key_XE.reg file still didn't exist at the expected location, so I don't know what it was supposed to do or what I am missing out on.  The blog states "To check if everything’s good, click on the windows start button -> All programs -> Oracle Database 11g Express Edition -> Get started.", which for me isn't listed in my start menu, so perhaps that's probably it.  Later on in the comments multiple users mention that the Get Started link should point to **http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1:3255401346727487**, which did take me to the Get Started page.

Comment: I had several failed attempts, before succeeding.  The important bit that wasn't mentioned is that regedit should be run as as administrator.  http://www.hanmiaojuan.com/2013/03/install-oracle-xe-11g-for-windows7-64bits.html has the most detailed instructions I've seen (besides which, it's soooo cute).

Comment: You will be able to install the 32 bit XE version on 64 bit Windows computer however, you will face many issues internally. I am using "OCI" driver for my application and it is unable to load the required dll. You will get an error like 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin\ocijdbc11.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform.
'

Answer (score 19):

I just installed the 32bit 11g R2 Express edition version on 64bit windows, created a new database and performed some queries. Seems to work like it should work! :-) I followed the following [easy guide](http://bpits.net/how-to-set-up-local-oracle-sql-database-in-3-steps/)!

Comment: Mirror: http://web.archive.org/web/20130728233907/http://bpits.net/how-to-set-up-local-oracle-sql-database-in-3-steps/

Answer (score 15):

Some of more advanced Oracle database features such as session trace do not work properly in Oracle 11g XE 32-bit if installed on Windows 64-bit system. I needed session trace on Windows 7 64-bit.

Apart from that it works well for me in multiple production MS Windows 64-bit systems: Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2003 R2.

Comment: Yep. Agreed, seems to work at a development system test level... which is what need it for anyways.

Answer (score 10):

This is a very useful question. It has 5 different helpful answers that say quite different but complementary things (surprising, eh?). This answer combines those answers into a more useful form as well as adding two more solutions.

There is no Oracle Express Edition for 64 bit Windows. See this official [but unanswered] [forum thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2279728?tstart=0).
Therefore, these are the classes of solutions:

- **Pay.** The paid versions of Oracle (Standard/Enterprise) support 64-bit Windows.
- **Hack.** Many people have successfully installed the 32 bit Oracle XE software on 64 bit Windows. [This blog post](http://luminite.wordpress.com/2012/09/06/installing-oracle-database-xe-11g-on-windows-7-64-bit-machine/) seems to be the one most often cited as helpful. This is unsupported, of course, and session trace is [known to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15565007/8373). But for many folks this is a good solution.
- **VM.** If your goal is simply to run Oracle on a 64 bit Windows machine, then running Oracle in a Virtual Machine may be a good solution. [VirtualBox](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html) is a natural choice because it's free and Oracle provides [pre-configured VMs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) with Oracle DB installed. VMWare or other virtualization systems work equally well.
- **Develop only.** Many users want Oracle XE just to learn Oracle or to test an application with Oracle. If that's your requirement, then [Oracle Enterprise Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-win64-download-1968077.html) (including support for 64-bit Windows) is free "only for the purpose of developing, testing, prototyping and demonstrating your application".

Answer (score 10):

Oracle 11G Express Edition is now available to install on 64-bit versions of Windows.

[Oracle 11G Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 7):

It's not available yet. See [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2277728&tstart=0) thread on the official forum.