# Which Oracle 11g R2 edition for learning to develop Web Applications

Tags: java, jsp, oracle11g, licensing

I'm starting to experiment with web applications using JSPs. I want to create a simple 
web app which will run locally connected with an Oracle 11gR2 database as well. 
If i understood Oracle's licensing i won't have any issues since Web Application won't be in Production, am i right?
Which Edition of Oracle would you recommend for a simple Web App running on Windows-64 bit?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19339128/991954) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Oracle 11g Express Edition. It should meet your needs.

Comment: I looked it up, but i only found a download link for 32-bit windows.

Comment: Then please specify in your question that you need a 64 bit edition

Answer (score 0):

Since you're experimenting, and if you're fairly new to Oracle or just aren't particularly interested in the DBA/installation side, you could consider [a pre-built VM image](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html). You can pick one that contains a database, SQL Developer and other tools; and whatever additional listed tools and technologies sounds most appropriate for the kind of things you'll be playing with.

As well as being very quick and easy to set up - no DBA knowledge required - it's completely isolated from any real environments you want to avoid interfering with, can run on any machine and O/S that runs VirtualBox, and best of all, if (or when) you really mess something up you can trash it and start again.

Comment: I am fairly new to Oracle but i am actually interested in the DBA/installation side. It might be a little more time-consuming but i guess it is worth the time! If i find it too much to handle for now i will definitely consider your solution.