# Oracle11gXE 64bit not installed correctly TNSListener not starting

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I am not sure if this is the right place for this question. I downloaded and installed Oracle11g XE 64bit edition in my Virtual Server ()

After this installation, TNSListener service is not starting at all. Initially I had the error message that it is configured as an Interactive Service. So I also started Interactive Service and then tried to start TNSListener, but it is not working. I tried this server time with uninstall oracle & reinstall also with system restarts. But nothing helps.

I did the same installation on my Windows Desktop 64 bit OS and here it works.

So, I don't understand where I am going wrong in my virtual server. Can someone pls help?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834410/oracle-11g-express-edition-for-windows-64bit

Comment: Hallo Andre. That's a very old post. Oracle now provides 64bit version for express editions.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem.

Key Note: When TNSListener wouldn't start via Windows Services, pls try the same via command prompt. We will get to know the error in detail.

This is what I did. Check my post http://www.umatechcorner.com/oracle-tnslistener-windows-service-wont-start-solved/